# Lossless extracting of JPEGs from an MJPEG video

Tags: software, video

Using the Timelapse app on my Sony NEX-6 camera, I get an AVI which contains an MJPEG stream.

However, I'd like to take all the individual frames into Lightroom as normal photos, to do my post-processing. Is there a way to extract the individual JPEG frames in a lossless fashion, e.g. *without resaving them*? As I understand it, MJPEG format is essentially just a lot of JPEG files contained within (in this case) an AVI container.

I would prefer to do this on a Mac (I normally use Lightroom and Photoshop), but any application that does it would be fine, I'll find an OS to run it!

Comment: Could you please add to the question which OS you're using and which photo/video editing applications you have? This helps people to answer your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is to use ffmpeg or avconv.

The command:

```
ffmpeg -i mjpegvideo.avi -vcodec copy frame%d.jpg
```

will create a series of jpeg without reencoding.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Photoshop you can open the MJPEG in Photoshop and apply the same edits there as you would in Lightroom.

The instructions below are carried out on a Mac with Photoshop CS5.1 but for Windows it should be comparable.

1. Open Photoshop
2. Open your MJPEG file
3. Go to `Window -> Workspace -> Motion`
4. Now a timeline appears on your screen where you can play and scrub through your footage.
5. Go to `Layer -> New Adjustment Layer` and choose the adjustment you want.
6. When you're done editing go to `File -> Export -> Render Video` and choose the desired video settings.

Make sure to use adjustment layers, as a simple adjustment will only affect one frame.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "*without re-saving them*" ... 
I use a software [freestudio](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/free-dvd-video-software.htm) to extract the JPEG files and then reorganize & edit the pix in LR,PS or AE...

Comment: Without re-saving means that the JPEG information is saved to file untouched, rather than a simple screen grab being made and then saved as JPEG (as would happen if the video was of another codec). As the MJPEGS are already compressed, I'd rather not re-compress them.

Comment: @RipperDoc i think this program actually extracts the frames, i'm not sure though cuz i never analyzed the data from the files this program created (maybe when i get home i'll check-if i remember...) anyway the program is free so u can try it out yourself & if it doesn't do the job just uninstall it afterwards

Comment: by without re-saving he means what's called `lossless` `extraction` (or, conversion), I think.

Comment: I think its really more like "no further losses" since both MPEG and JPEG are already lossy compression formats.  

Its important to note that a video frame may not be complete in the MPEG file, as the encoding uses a difference from prior frames, so you may have to include image data from many prior frames

Comment: Thanks Pat, but note that I am talking about MJPEG, not MPEG, which I think makes the case a bit different!